# R: Big integer matrices

Tags: r, memory, matrix

I have some big integer matrices (1000 x 1000000) that I have to multiply and do rowmax on.

They contain 0 and 1 (approx 99% 1 and 1% 0 and no other values).

My problem is memory consumption: Currently R eats 8 bytes per integer.

I have looked at SparseMatrix, but it seems I cannot set the default value to 1 instead of 0.

How can I represent these matrices in a memory efficient way, but so I can still multiply them as matrices and use rowmax?

Preferably it should work with R-2.15 and not require additional libraries.

Comment: there some reason you don't want to update your R?

Comment: Can you reassign 0 <-> 1?

Comment: @rawr The program is for external users that typically cannot update R.

Comment: @Hugh It would make the multiplication give the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Second idea: If you have a couple of these matrices, call them X_1 and X_2, let Y_1 = 1*1' - X_1 and Y_2 = 1*1' - X_2; the Y's can be sparse because they are 99% zero. So their product is

X_1 * X_2 = ( 1*1' - Y_1) * (1*1' - Y_2) = 1*1'*1*1' - Y_1*1*1' - 1*1'*Y_2 + Y_1 * Y_2

which you can simplify even further.

Comment: Also, if someone can edit that into formula's I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sparse matrix packages [slam](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=slam), [SparseM](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=SparseM), [Matrix](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=Matrix), ...) but I doubt any will do bitwise presentation, or even single char, as you'd need here.  You may have to code that up yourself.

Alternatively, packages like [ff](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=ff) allow more compact storage but AFAIK will not do matrix ops for you.  Maybe you could that on top of them?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I can't think of a packaged solution...

It seems like you could represent this type of data extremely efficiently with run length encoding by row. From there, you could implement a matrix-vector multiply method for rle objects, (which might be hard) and row-max (which should be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 1% 0's it would not be difficult to compress. One trivial example:

```
pseudo.matrix <- function(x){
  nrow <- nrow(x)
  ncol <- ncol(x)
  zeroes.cells <- which(x==0)
  p <- list(nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol, zeroes.cells=zeroes.cells)
}
```

This alone would reduce their memory size significantly. And it would be easy to recover the original matrix:

```
recover.matrix <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(1, x$nrow, x$ncol)
  for (i in x$zeroes.cells) m[i] <- 0
  m
}
```

I guess it is possible to figure out a way to efficiently multiply these pseudo matrices, since the result for each cell would be something like the number of columns of the first matrix minus an adjustment regarding the number of zeros in the operation, but I am not sure how easy it would be to do this.